# Implode array and insert dynamic data to mysql database

Tags: php, mysql

This is code for insert dynamic data to mysql database.

```
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($name); $i++) {
            if ($name[$i] != "") {
                $test= implode(", ", (array)$name[$i]);                    
                print_r($test);
 $sql = "INSERT INTO employee_table (name)
                     VALUES ('$test')";
            if ($conn->query($sql) === true) {
                echo ('ok');
            }              
                }
        }
        $conn->close();
```

I used `implode(", ", (array)$name[$i])` to returns a string from `$name` by comma but when `print_r($test);` like this:

```
AlexBrownHelloHugo
```

I got 2 problems and hope your help:

- Result when `print_r($test);` is `Alex,Brown,Hello,Hugo`
- Store `$test` [`Alex,Brown,Hello,Hugo`] same row into dabase.

Thanks all.

Comment: What's the value of `$_POST['name']`?

Comment: Value of `$_POST['name'][0] is Alex`,
`_POST['name'][1] is Brown` ...

Comment: Then your `$name` itself is an array which you can convert into a string using `implode(",", $name)` outside the loop. Use the string to insert as well.

Comment: its a bad idea to store data as a delimited list when you can make it a related table.  In any case I would save it as this `,Alex,Brown,Hello,Hugo,`  with leading and trailing delimiters, that way when you query it you can do this `field LIKE '%,Alex,%'`.  The difference is if you have `foo,some,bar` and `foo,something,bar` and you do `field LIKE '%some%'`  note no `,` you will find both of those `some` and `something`.  To query the first and last items like I showed above with `,` they would need the `,` around them.  You can just use `trim($field, ',')` to remove them before explode etc.

Comment: I also don't know why you would use `for` instead of `foreach` which would be way easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
$names = empty($_POST['name']) ? [] : $_POST['name'];

foreach($names AS $name){
    if (!empty($name)) {
          $test= '['.implode(", ", (array)$name).']';                    
          print_r($test);
          $sql = "INSERT INTO employee_table (name)
                 VALUES ('$test')";
          if ($conn->query($sql) === true) {
            echo ('ok');
         }              
    }
}
```

I wanted to repost this comment I made:

> its a bad idea to store data as a delimited list when you can make it a related table. In any case I would save it as this `,Alex,Brown,Hello,Hugo,` with leading and trailing delimiters, that way when you query it you can do this `field LIKE '%,Alex,%'`. The difference is if you have `foo,some,bar` and `foo,something,bar` and you do `field LIKE '%some%'` note no `,` you will find both of those some and something. To query the first and last items like I showed above with `,` they would need the `,` around them. You can just use `trim($field, ',')` to remove them before explode etc

**UPDATE**

And this one

> its unclear the structure of `$name` is it `implode($name[$i])` or `impode($name)` You use the first one in your code which implies name is `[['foo','bar'], [...]]` not `['foo','bar', ...]` If it's the second your also storing it multiple times which you probably don't want.

So you may be able to do just this:

```
//$_POST['name'] = ['foo','bar', ...]

//remove the loop

 //we can assign $name in the if condition and save a line or 2
 //the second part, the assignment, will always return true.
if (!empty($_POST['name']) && $name = $_POST['name']) {
      $test= '['.implode(',', (array)$name).']';   //changed mainly this line                 
      print_r($test);
      $sql = "INSERT INTO employee_table (name) VALUES ('$test')";
      if ($conn->query($sql) === true) {
         echo 'ok';
      }              
}
```

With no loop, because when you loop over the count of names, your inserting the same data each time, up to the number of items in the names variable.

**Explaining your code**

So with my example data `$_POST['name'] = ['foo','bar', ...]` and a simplified version of your original code, you would be doing this:

*Assuming you meant `implode($name)` and not `implode($name[$i])` in your original code, which is the only sane thing if your data looks like my example data*

```
 //canned example data
$name = ['foo','bar'];

for ($i = 0; $i < count($name); $i++) {
    if ($name[$i] != "") {
        $test= implode(", ", (array)$name);  //changed from $name[$i] 

        //just output this stuff so we can see the results                 
        print_r($test);
        echo "\nINSERT INTO employee_table (name) VALUES ('$test')\n";
    }
}
```

Outputs:

```
foo, bar
INSERT INTO employee_table (name) VALUES ('foo, bar')
foo, bar
INSERT INTO employee_table (name) VALUES ('foo, bar')
```

[Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/b2d14d5981e185eff5ea6e33032f3fc97df5bb42)

If should be obvious but if you changed this line `$test= implode(", ", (array)$name);` to `$test= '['.implode(',', (array)$name).'];` in the above code the output would be this:

```
foo, bar
INSERT INTO employee_table (name) VALUES ('[foo,bar]')
foo, bar
INSERT INTO employee_table (name) VALUES ('[foo,bar]')
```

Which still saves it more then one time.  So we need to dump that loop, which basically forces us into the code I put at the top of this update.

Hopefully that all makes sense.

Cheers

Comment: Thanks for your help. It worked but it can't store $test in Database

Comment: its unclear the structure of `$name` is it `implode($name[$i])` or `impode($name)`  You use the first one in your code which implies name is `[['foo','bar'], [...]]` not `['foo','bar', ...]`  If it's the second your also storing it multiple times which you probably don't want.

Comment: `but it can't store $test in Database` I didn't modify any of the DB stuff, so if it saved before it should still work now.

Comment: Can you please help me store it in database?

Comment: Sure, but this doesn't help me `but it can't store $test in Database`, nor does the lack of example data for `$name`.  Not to mention I have no idea if it originally stored the data in there or not.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, in fact your `$_POST['name']` store your value as an array, so you don't need to cast it.

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
for ($i = 0; $i < count($name); $i++) {
      if ($name[$i] != "") {
          $test= '['.implode(', ', $_POST['name']).']';                    
          print_r($test);
          $sql = "INSERT INTO employee_table (name)
                     VALUES ('$test')";
          if ($conn->query($sql) === true) {
             echo ('ok');
          }              
      }
}
$conn->close();
```